How to properly set up upstream balancing for ingresses in different kubernetes clusters?
I want to send a request between two clusters using nginx on a separate server
there is an nginx server to route via upstream to two identical backends in two different clusters
, let's say the validator application is deployed in two clusters and has different ingress addresses
validator.amd.com
validator.bm.com
I set it up on nginx like this
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.test.com;
    location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
               }
}
upstream valid{
server validator.amd.com:80;
server  validator.bm.com:80;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.test.com;
     ssl_certificate test.test.com.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key test.test.com.key;



    location / {
     return 204;
    }

    location /keepalive {
       return 200;
               }
    location /api/valid {
        proxy_set_header Content-Type application/json;
        proxy_pass http://valid/api/validators;

    }
}

it doesn't work at all through the upstream
, but if I proxy
location /api/valid {
        proxy_set_header Content-Type application/json;
        proxy_pass http://validator.amd.com/api/validators;

    }

then everything is OK, similarly, if you put another domain
, I do not understand what the catch might be and why everything works directly, and if there is no upstream, please tell me?
I also tried adding headers

proxy_set_header Host $host; proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; proxy_set_header
Content-Type application/json;


Check if the DNS resolution is working properly for both validator.amd.com and validator.bm.com using ‘dig’ command on nginx server. Also, check the logs of the nginx server which may provide you some information about why the upstream is not working properly. You can use this command for checking it: ‘less /var/log/nginx/error.log’

If you have configured health checks on the upstream, make sure that both of the servers are properly responding to health checks.
